# Explore .obj files generated by VC++

Tags: c++, windows, object

Is there any utility or command available to explore the symbols within object files generated by MSVC++ compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [dumpbin /SYMBOLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) can do this.

Comment: Thanks. any way to get the results into more readable or formatted form?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. I don't think `dumpbin` provides any extra formatting - you will have to use other tools to change it.